# i want to initialize overflow attribute as none in BIRT tool

Tags: birt

[image]

But if i select none ,its showing as hidden:inherited. please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Just change it old-skool style: edit XML

Answer (score 0):

A value of "none" is not supported and you will receive an error if you try to change it in XML. You can add JavaScript to change or remove the value in the DOM.